# React Native Iterate through Object After Button Click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to make it so that I can click a button and go to the next object in my json file. But I am unsure how to continue the for loop on click. I tried adding an i++ to the onpress event in the button but that doesnt work and just errors as I think on press needs to be a function. Any help would be fantastic! I am very new to react-native so sorry if this isnt the way to do it

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Image,
    Button
} from 'react-native';

var jsonData = require('./skull.json');

export default class flashcards extends Component {
    render() {
        var i = 0;

        for (i; i < 50; i++) {
            var skull = jsonData[i];
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text>
                        Question #{jsonData.quiz.question[i].number}
                    </Text>

                    <Text>
                        {jsonData.quiz.question[i].question}
                    </Text>
                    <Image
                        source={{ uri: jsonData.quiz.question[i].picture }}
                        style={styles.thumbnail}
                    />
                    <Button
                        title="Next Question"
                        color="#841584"
                        accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
                    />
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF'
    },
    thumbnail: {
        width: 300,
        height: 350
    }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('flashcards', () => flashcards);
```

Comment: I feel your approach is wrong. I think you should use Navigator. More details: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.23/docs/navigator.html

Comment: Create a state variable that keeps track of which is the currentItem, when pressed it sets the currentItem state variable to the current one, which should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Ya I think you need to create `state` to increase your `i` , and set the state on your `onPress` event like this :

```
export default class flashcards extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {i: 0};
  }

  onButtonPress = () => {
    if(this.state.i < 50){
      this.setState({
        i: this.state.i + 1
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        ....//your code

        <Button
          onPress={this.onButtonPress}
          title="Next Question"
          color="#841584"
          accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
        />

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

And to call json data you have to change `i` with `this.state.i` like this :

`jsonData.quiz.question[this.state.i].question`

For more details you have to understand about `state` on react native, you can read on the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state.html). I hope this answer can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this because **this.setState** will cause **50 times** to **re-render** when You do **this.setState** in loop.

```
export default class flashcards extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {i: 0};
  }

  onButtonPress = () => {
    let val = this.state.i;
    if(val < 50){
      va += 1
    }
    this.setState({ i: val });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        ....//your code

        <Button
          onPress={this.onButtonPress}
          title="Next Question"
          color="#841584"
          accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
        />

      </View>
    );
  }
}
```